# Playback start of wave file from memory and the rest from disk

Tags: python, performance, audio, wave, preloading

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of a python-based musical instrument (a midi keyboard that triggers .wav samples on a Raspberry Pi3). Currently all samples are loaded into memory for low latency playback using python-sounddevice. This works for smaller sample sets, but for a 1GB grand piano sample set, the load time is upwards of 30 seconds.

Playback directly from disk solves this problem, but introduces higher latency which is no good for musical instruments.

Is there a way to preload the first chunk of each sample into memory, playback that chunk from memory, then have the rest of the file play directly from disk? Or is there an entirely different solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: This seems quite broad, no?

Comment: Perhaps my approach to a solution covers a too broader area, but the issue of performance is surely pretty specific